# MongoDB shell to JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, command-line-interface

I want to output MongoDB records to static JSON so I can load it in another program for analysis.

I got as far as:

```
mongo "mongodb://root:$MONGO_PASSWORD@$MONGO_CONNECT" users.js
```

with `users.js` looking like:

```
cursor = db.users.find()
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  printjson(cursor.next())
}
```

But the stdout has a couple of problems. It includes the Mongo shell output and connection info. And the JSON isn't valid / properly concatenated.

What's a better approach to getting JSON out of Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) is what you're looking for. It outputs your collection as a text format:

Try

```
mongoexport --db yourdb --collection users --uri "mongodb://root:$MONGO_PASSWORD@$MONGO_CONNECT" --out users.json
```

Will output:

```
{_id: "id1", field1: "field1Val...", ...}
{_id: "id2", field1: "field1Val...", ...}
```

So each line will contain single document from your collection

Comment: Since it's not comma delimited, it's not valid JSON or am I missing something? Nonetheless `jq` groks it.

Comment: @hendry each line is a valid JSON, alternatively you can try `--jsonArray` option if it makes more sense for you to have one array of documents